# is it possible to make sure the client used is from a particular host?

Tags: java, security, certificate

I have a server application and a client application created with java that will communicate with the server application. But, since i haven't put emphasis on security in the server side it is really easy to hack the server application if a hacker creates his own client to connect with my server. I want to make sure the client application that is communicating with my server is the authentic client that i created. I upload client to a specific host like www.abcd.com. Now, can i make sure when a client that connects to my server came from that host. I am knowledgeable about signing it with trusted signer but i am looking for a cheap option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. If it were, DRM would work, but everyone knows it's hopelessly broken.

To be truly secure, the client has to be a machine with a "trusted platform module," [TPM,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) that supports something called remote attestation. This allows the server to verify the client is authentic and unaltered. But I've never heard of a real world application of this, and though TPMs are common, I'm not sure if the remote attestation feature is.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make sure the client application that is communicating with my server is the authentic client that i created.

You have two options. One is a password or shared secret, and the other is client certificates. All three are supported in SSL/TLS. Look for TLS-SRP (password based authenticated key exchange), TLS_PSK (preshared key based on a block cipher), and the traditional SSLTLS ciphers with client side certificates.

You can even set up the tunnel with Server Authentication only, and then perform the client authentication at the application level. This is what usually happens in web apps. But this has some non-trivial defects because it does *not* provide mutual authentication and lacks channel binding. You are better off with TLS-SRP, TLS-PSK, or client certificates.

**EDIT**: I focused on SSL/TLS because you cited a hostname, but you can do it at other layers, too. For example, you can use shared secrets and certificates at the VPN level. @erickson provides one method using TPMs that could be used at the application level.

---

> Now, can i make sure when a client that connects to my server came from that host.... host like www.abcd.com

This will work if DNS is configured and trustworthy. That is, you will have to extract the host's name, perform a reverse lookup, and then authenticate the IP address. I believe this is called network based authentication.

If an attacker controls DNS or is on the same LAN segment as the server, then I believe network based authentication has some non-trivial security defects.

---

In any case, HSMs and TPMs are not the answer. To understand why, see Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf), and the section on Unattended Key Storage. From his book:

> TPMs don’t work because all that they can do is store the fixed key
>   that’s required to decrypt the other keys (TPMs are just repurposed
>   smart cards and don’t have the horsepower to perform anything more
>   than lightweight crypto themselves so you can’t offload the overall
>   encryption processing to them), and since for unattended operation
>   they have to release their secrets without a PIN being entered they’re
>   just providing plaintext key storage with one level of indirection.

Comment: I don't understand how any of this prevents an attacker from creating their own client. The OP wants to make sure that clients are using software downloaded from www.abcd.com, not that they are connecting from www.abcd.com. And any embedded keys can be extracted and used in the attacker's client.

Comment: The keys should not be embedded. They are provisioned, and each client gets a distinct key.

Comment: What's to stop an attacker from using the provisioned key in his corrupt client?

Comment: Right. That's a risk they must accept when dealing with software on commodity hardware. Another risk is the key will be stolen by an adversary, and the adversary will misuse it.